# Scala test error: value / is not a member of sbt.Configuration

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, functional-testing

I am transitioning from Java to scala and is following https://medium.com/@geovannyjs/functional-tests-with-scala-sbt-play-framework-specs2-and-one-application-per-test-suite-22ddf70e5cbe t**o write my initial functional test.**

My test is going well except the part that it is **not** calling setup() and cleanup() that are described towards the end of this doc. Hence, following the doc, added :

```
Test / fork := false
Test / testOptions += Tests.Setup(_.loadClass("common.Resources").getMethod("setup").invoke(null))
Test / testOptions += Tests.Cleanup(_.loadClass("common.Resources").getMethod("cleanup").invoke(null))
```

in my **build.sbt**. After that I started getting **compilation error:**

```
error: value / is not a member of sbt.Configuration
```

in

```
Test / fork := false
```

**May I get any insight on what am I doing wrong?**

This are the libraries that I am using:

```
lazy val thirdPartyDependencies = Seq(
jdbc,
"com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1",
"com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.4.0.jre8",
"io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.0",  // This version adds Play 2.4 support.
// ScalaTest+ Play (have to use non-release 1.4.0-M4 version for now as it is only compatible with Play 2.4)
"org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0-M4" % "test",
"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % "test",
specs2 % Test
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of SBT which does not support this syntax.

Either set `sbt.version` in `project/build.properties` to some 1.1+ version or use the older syntax:

```
fork in Test := false
```